# MySql Workbench on Ubuntu 14.04 Create Table editor not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My system:
Dell Inspiron 5000 laptop
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
64 bit OS

I installed MySql Workbench 6.0. If I attempt to create a new table using the GUI, the table editor opens and suggests a first column. None of the fields (auto increment, not null, etc) can be checked, and no additional columns can be added. The table editor does not respond in any way to clicks or mouse motions

I would appreciate advice on how to correct the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your MySQL Workbench to newest version - you can download it from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/. Then if problem still exists fill bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com/